# How to clear/delete published Platform event from EventBus after sometime?

Tags: apex, subscriber, platform-event, publisher

I'm publishing Platform Events using [APEX Code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_publish_apex.htm) 
`EventBus.publish` method and consuming the events in backend Java app using EventListener.

**Problem**

All the published events remains in EventBus and whenever my consumer Java app restarts, listener is receiving all the previously published events (in the past 24 hrs?, not sure about the timing though).

Is there any way to clear the events published to EventBus after some set interval? I've gone through the Platform Events documentation and couldn't find any help to tackle this problem.

Any pointer would be helpful

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a feature called [Event Durability](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/using_streaming_api_durability.htm). It is *expected* that the client retains the last `replayId` it has seen, and pass this in to the streaming handshake to resume where they left off. There's no way to clear this early and yet provide durability. The events do drop off after 24 hours. You will need to modify your code to remember the last `replayId`.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction to track `replayId`. Will play around.

Answer (score 5):

You **cannot** delete Platform Event records. This is mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_intro_emp.htm?search_text=delete):

> Unlike custom objects, you **can’t** **update** or **delete** event records.

The only way you can delete event records is by deleting its definition altogether:

> When you delete a platform event definition, it’s permanently deleted.

Comment: +1 lol you beat me by 6 seconds!